# jQuery UI autocomplete is not working with ajax loaded form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

this is my code and I am using jQuery UI to implement an autocomplete field

```
 jQuery( function() {
    jQuery( ".product-category" ).on('keydown.autocomplete', {
        source: ''
    });
} );
```

but jQuery UI autocomplete is not working for dynamically generated text fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement autocomplete on dynamically generated input elements as.

```
var selector = 'input.searchInput';
$(document).on('keydown.autocomplete', selector, function() {
    $(this).autocomplete(options);
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/waw2vhb7/

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to reload your jQuery function after the DOM changes / form is done loading from the ajax request. jQuery only detects DOM that's currently loaded when it runs.